# Arch Linux KDE GDlauncher Not Working

Tags: minecraft

When I try to install Mods on GDLauncher, it sometimes stays at 0%. It will not change after left for about 20 minutes. I am using an unofficial bin launcher since that is the only way I can do it. I have tried closing and reopening. I also prefer not getting an answer about uninstalling and reinstalling the app since I do not remember the password. Here is a provided image for reference.

[image: The modin the top left corner is not downloading.]

If there is anything wrong with my question please tell me so I can fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue and has nothing to do with your setup. See the [related github issue](https://github.com/gorilla-devs/GDLauncher/issues/1154)

Some mentioned that installing the latest development build fixes the problem.

OT:
You might want to think about getting a password manager instead of loosing passwords.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: `loosing passwords`? you mean `losing passwords`. Sorry, this misspelling continually irritates me.

Comment: @Bib I've written it as it was meant. `losing` has a different meaning that the one I've intended.

Comment: It is fully updated. I did hear somewhere about how the arch linux OS is outdated though... Also this information may help: It is not an official package, it is an AUR. (Packages made by the community)

Comment: This is the first time I've heard someone saying arch is outdated smh. You might want to try debian then, it is much more up to date **/s** .

 I was not talking about a release but specifically about a **developer build** as mentioned [in this github comment](https://github.com/gorilla-devs/GDLauncher/issues/1266#issuecomment-1026151091)

Comment: I think id rather just have a unreliable minecraft launcher than have to wipe my memory and getting a new operating system.

Comment: @mashuptwice loosing means untightening or releasing. These often get mixed up.